# Enhancing reliability of RabbitMQ library pika or are there better alternatives

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika, reliability

## A brief overview

I have a microservice architecture powered by Python 3.6+ where it processes an upwards of 10 million transactions per day through RabbitMQ.

A significant part of the architecture is a set of 16-32 parallel consumers launched as `multiprocessing.Process` instances that fetch and process these transactions from RabbitMQ.

The library currently used for interfacing with RabbitMQ through Python is `pika`

## What are the issues and challenges?

The BlockingConnection adapter of `pika` is rather unreliable. I believe it maintains its own polling loop. Under a sudden burst of transactions, the connections get dropped.

I have retries configured in a jitter, exponential back-off model through the `tenacity` Python library, watching on the base exception pika.exceptions.AMQPError.

But in spite of this safeguard, the connections are dropped abruptly:

`104:Connection Reset by Peer`
or

```
in basic_publish
   raise exceptions.ChannelClosed()
pika.exceptions.ChannelClosed
```

Looking at the Asynchronous implementations of pika [consumer](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.11.2/examples/asynchronous_consumer_example.html) and [publisher](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.11.2/examples/asynchronous_publisher_example.html),

- it looks like a tangled up mess of callbacks with no properly documented sequence
- the added complexity that I assume of running this event loop based consumer in a separate thread in a multiprocessing based architecture and communicating back the results to the process that actually needs it

### The question being: What is a stabler alternative to pika?

I came across [amqp](https://amqp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Their homepage mostly has an API reference without any usage patterns or examples documented.

Is this a stable enough library to dig into?
Or are there any better alternatives?

Comment: Many people successfully use Pika in high-throughput workloads. Rather than place the blame on Pika I suggest that you provide your source code, without which I can't give suggestions to help out. You don't provide important information like what versions of software are you using (RabbitMQ, Erlang, operating system), what version of Pika, what is a "sudden burst of transactions" vs the normal rate, are you setting prefetch (QoS), what is shown in the RabbitMQ logs. If this information can be provided, I suggest following up on the `rabbitmq-users` or `pika-python` google groups.